# Using PHP what is the most efficent way to convert a string of index's to thier name value from a database?

Tags: php, mysqli

Assuming I have established a connection to the database and all is well. How can I iterate efficiently through a string like
`$item ["tags"]=>
  string(54) "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,9,10,11,12,13,14,17,18,19,20,21,25,28,31"`

and replace these index values with the name stored in a "tags" database table like ...

**id ......... Name**
1 .......... Relationships
2 .......... Services
3 .......... Counseling

Using php and mysqli... Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could insert them into a temporary table and do a JOIN, but I bet that's inefficient.

Comment: Just issue a SELECT with an IN clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with :

```
                    if ( $item->tags ) {

        $eachTag = explode(",", $item->tags);

            foreach ($eachTag as $key => $value) {
                $result = mysql_query("SELECT `name`,`id` from tags WHERE `id`=$value");
                $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);

                if ($row != "") {
                    $tagsWithName .= $row['name'].", ";
                }   
            }
        $tagsWithName = rtrim($tagsWithName, ", ");
```

There is probably better though ...

Answer (score 3):

You could use the following:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli("host", "user", "password", "database");
$sql = sprintf("SELECT id, Name FROM table_name WHERE id IN (%s)", $mysqli->escape_string($item['tags']));
```

If you use $sql as the query string, the query result will be a array of rows with `id`s matching their `Name`. If you want it to have a structure like `$array[<id>] = <name>`, consider doing the following:

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql);
if($result->num_rows > 0) {
    $returnArray = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
        $returnArray[$row['id']] = $row['Name'];
    }
}
```

What this will do, is query your MySQL server, check if the SQL query returned any result and if it did it'll parse the result all in an array where you have  a `id -> Name` structure.